# How do I run a program?

Tags: command-line, bash

This is something dumbfounded on me. I am trying to run a program found in current directory and I keep getting "command not found" despite being right in the current directory.

I have tried "./program.bin", ".program.bin", and "/program.bin" but it still generates an error saying no command found despite being right in current directory. Remember, this is not a program found in bin folder, it's only found in current directory I am in.

Why? I am on Lubuntu as well and I get the same error. Is there a requirement that I have to somehow "install" the program.bin to make it run? Or what?

UPDATE: found that it cannot run because it's not an executable until you selected "Make the file executable" in permissions dialog.

Comment: If you do `ls -l` on the program what are its attributes and ownership?  It may not be marked as executable, at least by you.

Comment: Yep, that's because it was not treated as an executable file. I selected "executable" in properties of file and it started as an executable.

Comment: Is "command not found" the entire message, with no other information prefixing it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the program executable first by issuing the following command

```
chmod u+x program.bin
```

This adds the executable bit for the user

if the executable flag is not set then you can usually run most commands by calling bash like so

```
bash ./program.bin
```

however since this is a .bin file I am not sure how the previous command would work. It would be better to add the executable bit